# Zepto greater than selector

Tags: javascript, selector, zepto

Is it possible to do something like this in Zepto for selecting elements greater or less than an index:

```
$( "td:gt(4)" ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
$( "td:gt(-2)" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

as on https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer: According to [zepto js](http://zeptojs.com/) **JQuery CSS extensions are not supported**.  Zepto has some CSS extended selectors ([github](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/selector.js#files)) but that also does not support the functionality that you are looking for.